# Can I use PHP to dynamically insert url, media and description with Pinterest?

Tags: php, javascript, pinterest

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
window.PinIt = window.PinIt || { loaded:false };
if (window.PinIt.loaded) return;
window.PinIt.loaded = true;
function async_load(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    if (window.location.protocol == "https:")
        s.src = "https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
    else
        s.src = "http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", async_load);
else
    window.addEventListener("load", async_load, false);
})();
</script>

 <!-- Customize and include for EACH button in the page -->
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')-       >getCurrentUrl(); ?>&media=<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(500); ?>&description=<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
```

The php successfully gathers all of the elements and when I click on the button, it pops up the modal window.

However, in the subsequent modal window, it does not pin to my board when I'm logged in.

The Script tag and link are both inside of a list item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Moises M.

Comment: Is your question about the the Pinterest or about passing data to JavaScript from PHP? Do some debugging and find out the exact point where this is failing. It will make it easier for someone to help you, and you might discover the problem yourself.

Comment: It's about Pinterest. I've used their code @nicholaides , and I've contacted them, but I wanted to see if anyone else had this problem.

Comment: In that case, I suggest removing any code that's not specifically highlighting the problem with Pinterest. It will be easier for people to know what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like the problem is that you are not url encoding the parameters, i.e. everything after the ?url=

I'm not sure if that's the only problem you'll run into with this, but it should fix the one you're currently hitting!

Comment: It was a combination of this, and not having a fully setup test Pinterest account. Thanks!